# Download wheel for Numpy on pip install during CI (instead of building it)

Tags: python, numpy, continuous-integration, python-wheel

When doing continuous integration (e.g. on Github Actions or CircleCI) for a Python project with a dependency on Numpy, the integration workflow will build Numpy wheel from source every single time.

This results in an integration workflow which it much longer than what it could be without this step.

Is there a way to tell `pip` to download the wheel from a remote location instead of building it from source? Also, subsequent question, is there a known location which hosts up to date Numpy wheels for various platforms?

Comment: What OS and Python version(s) do you use at CIs? How do you install NumPy during CI? Anything more than just `pip install numpy`?

Comment: @phd for CI we use Ubuntu latest with Python 3.8. Installing with only `pip install pandas` which depends on NumPy

Comment: Then it's strange. The current version of  numpy 1.20.1 [releases](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.20.1/#files) all possible wheels for Python 3.8 for Linux — 32- and 64-bit, manylinux1 and manylinux2010.